# difference between jdk and bdk?

Tags: java

difference between jdk and bdk ?

Comment: bdk-bean development kit

Answer (score 1):

Jdk is the standard developers kit to work in Java

Bdk is a product of Sun that include on top of Jdk other products to develop Java Beans.

http://java.sun.com/products/bdk/

Answer (score 0):

The JDK usually refers to the standard [Java Development Kit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Development_Kit), i.e. the `javac` compiler, other binaries such as `javap`, the standard library etc.

BDK is (according to [allinterview.com](http://www.allinterview.com/showanswers/2497.html)):

> *Bean Development Kit is a tool that enables to create,configure and connect a set of Beans and it can be used to test Beans without writing a code.*

and according to mindprods glossary:

> *Bean Development Kit. It is now obsolete. Code-building features of modern IDEs take over much of the function of the BDK.*